# CakePHP controller custom function not recognized

Tags: php, function, cakephp

I'm learning CakePHP and following [this](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started.html#blog-tutorial) tutorial.

In implementing the DELETE control, I decided to create a custom function to contain some duplicating lines of code. However, my custom function is not recognized when I attempt to call it.

My code is as follows:

```
class PostsController extends AppController{
public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');

public function index(){
    $this->set('posts', $this->Post->find('all'));
}//index

public function view($id = null){
    if(!$id){
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid Post'));
    }

    $post = $this->Post->findById($id);
    if(!$post){
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid Post'));
    }

    $this->set('post', $post);
}//view

public function add(){
    if($this->request->is('post')){
        $this->Post->create();
        if($this->Post->save($this->request->data)){
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your post has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to add your post.'));
    }
}//add

public function edit($id=null){

    idCheck($id);

    $post = $this->Post->findById($id);
    if(!$post)
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));

    if($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))){
        $this->Post->id = $id;
        if($this->Post->save($this->request->data)){
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your post has been updated!'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to update your post.'));
    }

    if(!$this->request->data)
        $this->request->data = $post;
}//edit

public function delete($id=null){
    idCheck($id);
}

public function idCheck($id=null){
    if(!$id)
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Post ID required'));

    if(!is_numeric($id))
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Post ID must be numeric'));
}
}
```

All I'm trying to do is call my **idCheck()** function but I get this error:

> Error: Call to undefined function idcheck()

Comment: You can't use it like that, you have to call it as `$this->idCheck($id);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in cakephp you cant call functions directly.

See you play with object ,and if you want to call function that belongs to current object , use

```
$this->Your_function();
```

According to your question,use:

```
$this->idCheck($id);
```

It means call function `idCheck()` function for current object.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot the object oriented nature of the code. Is it correct to call the function staticly - i:e - $this::idCheck($id) ??

Comment: Hi static functions are called by classnane ,not object.